# Vader - Lack of Jobs Disturbing. Add Business Level to Create More

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Anyone else get this message from vader?

Yesterday I tried to move a bit to another job and when I hit the job button under him I got this message from vader.

No big deal, but I've built 2 new jobs since then and I still get this message. The problem is I have no unemployed bitizens. So now I have these new jobs and I have 10 bits that I could choose from that have the 2 new jobs as there dream job but when I try and move them from there current job I keep getting this create more jobs message from vader. Sorry for the bad explanation.

My question is, has anyone else had this and if so, have they gotten past it to where they can move bits from job to job again?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question.   I have not yet experienced this.  Have you tried moving them to unemployed first, then to the open spot?

Comment: As soon as i hit the job button to unemploy or move bit to another job I get that message. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a possible glitch after updating to 1.1.2  http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?p=90701473 but I am on 1.1.2 and just moved a bitzen to unemployed and back to a job - no message from Vader.... What version are you on?  (open the menu and click on the wrench)

Comment: 1.1.2064. I just finished my 3 rd level after the message from vader, and it's letting me move bits now. Thanks for the input ø

Comment: I started getting this today too.  I'm on 1.1.2064 and it's quite annoying.  I just had some bits move in who are 9s at their favorite job, and I can't employ them because I can't move the former bit out of the way.  Follow the link to the forum page, the latest update is buggy, hope they get a fix soon.

Comment: Damn!! It's happening again and I just built a res. floor and got 3-9s and I have their dream jobs. I'm really thinking it's something that happens when you reach a certain point of the game to make it harder. How many floors do you have Jeff? It did it for me at 28 floors and did it again at 32.

Comment: It seems to me like this happens when you have 0 open jobs.  When I get a new business level, I can move people just fine, but the second 3 people are working, I can't move anyone anywhere without evicting.

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest build 1.2.2268, this bug has been resolved.  You can now select an employed bitizen and choose to send them to unemployment.  You will only get this screen when you click on the job of an unemployed bitizen and you have no jobs available.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's annoying. The trick I found is to always keep one spot opened, usually from a very low income job. If you don't have any, you just have to evict one. ;)